# Gdb 7.9.1 with eclipse on OSX Yosemite

Tags: gcc, gdb, osx-yosemite, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse LUNA CDT on my Mac OSX Yosemite and I recently set up GDB 7.9.1 on my machine to debug my applications.
I noticed that the debug session is very poor: no step run per instruction, no stop on break points, I can not watch the variables content or visualise the memory (stack/heap) etc...
Does anyone use GDB for the same purpose?
Is this a limitation of Eclipse or did I install a wrong version somewhere in my development environment?

Thanks for help.

I show the following versions of my development environment:

- Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
- gcc --version

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix

- gdb --version

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0".

Answer (score 0):

Apple phased out support for GDB 7.9.1 in favor of LLDB beginning with Yosemite. Unfortunately Eclipse CDT doesn't support LLDB.

- Try installing the mac ports version of gdb and the apple-gcc
  compiler:

  ```
  $ sudo port install gdb-apple
  $ sudo port install apple-gcc42
  ```
- Code sign gdb-apple after you create a system cert for it:

  ```
  codesign -s gdb-cert $(which gdb-apple)
  ```
- Restart the taskgated process.
- Set the debugger in eclipse to use gdb-apple instead of gdb , it
  should be installed to /opt/local/bin/gdb-apple

More details can be found here
http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/